# Features should be at same order in train and test?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training, feature-engineering

I train ensemble model

- Logistic regression
- random forest
- adaboost class

With pcr and random search
In pipeline.

The features in the train and test are Equal but not in the same order.
Will it be okay if the features are not in the same order?

Comment: This completely depends on how the features are selected from the dataset, by name or by an index. If the first it doesn't matter, for the second one it does. In other words, it completely depends on what library/methods you are using to create your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks but if the order is feature1 and feature2 in train and test feature2 and feature1 why its different if its index (iloc) or name

Comment: If you select a column by name, it doesn't matter if the column is first or second, as long as the name stays the same it will select the same data. However, if you select a column by index (e.g. select the first column), it will matter which column is first.

Comment: Could you include the some more details? Such as a data sample and the specific implementations of the algo's?